# link elements in joint.js dissapear when mousing over them.

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am buillding an FSA application in joint.js using the fsa plugin. However, whenever I mouse over the links, they disappear.

This is the relevant javascript code:

```
function link(source, target, label, maxsize) {
  var vertices = []
  if (source.id == target.id) {
       vertices = [{ x:source.attributes.position.x+10*maxsize, y:source.attributes.position.y-40 }, { x:source.attributes.position.x+10*maxsize, y:source.attributes.position.y+40 }]; 
  }   
  var w = parseInt(label,10);
  if (source.id == init.id || target.id == term.id) 
      label = ""; 
  var cell = new joint.shapes.fsa.Arrow({
      source: { id: source.id },
      target: { id: target.id },
       labels: [{ position: .5, attrs: { text: { text: label || '', 'font-weight': 'bold' } } }], 
      vertices: vertices || []
  }); 
  cell.weight = w;
  return cell;
```

}

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems you must be getting some error to the browser console. Can you post it here? It looks like something else is wrong, not the code that you posted. However, I see you're accessing `source.attributes.position.x` directly. Note that this is not part of the public API. You should use source.get('position').x.